# move svg needle vertically upward and downward

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg of thermometer to show the temperature level. The thermometer should update the value with the provided value. To show the value in thermometer, a needle should move either top or bottom. When i used sketch, i see the needle position is controlled through height and y axis but i dont see such in the code. How can i animate that svg when using javascript for animation?

I have attached svg to figure out 
http://svgshare.com/s/1C9

This is the part of the needle as per the code

```
<path d="M84.9986191,1309.78732 C72.406414,1313.07575 63.2874461,1323.22544 63.2874461,1335.30443 L63.2874461,1423.54578 C63.2874461,1438.30467 76.922373,1450.19253 93.8469462,1450.19253 C110.771519,1450.19253 124.379137,1438.30467 124.379137,1423.54578 L124.379137,1335.30443 C124.379137,1323.22544 115.260169,1313.07575 102.667964,1309.78732 L102.667964,844.512322 L84.9986191,844.512322 L84.9986191,1309.78732 Z" id="needle" stroke="#000000" strokeWidth="2.13166976" fill="#FF0000"></path>
```

UPDATE

I want to move the rect not the line https://jsfiddle.net/8nLp81n0/

Comment: Why are you posting the same question under multiple accounts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304225/animate-line-of-svg-based-on-user-provided-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you understand my previous suggestion?

```js
var mercury = document.getElementById("mercury");
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

var yFor0 = 358;
var yFor100 = 50;

slider.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
  var sliderValue = evt.target.value;
  displayTemperature(sliderValue);
});

function displayTemperature(temp)
{
  var mercuryY = yFor0 + (temp * (yFor100 - yFor0)) / 100;
  mercury.setAttribute("y1", mercuryY);
}
```

```css
svg {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="500">
  <line id="mercury" x1="40" y1="50" x2="40" y2="500" stroke="red" stroke-width="20"/>
  <rect x="30" y="30" width="20" height="469" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
  
  <text x="60" y="55">100</text>
  <text x="60" y="363">0</text>
  <text x="60" y="455">-30</text>
</svg>

<input id="slider" type="range" min="-30" max="100" step="1" value="100"/>
```

**Update - Rectangle**

The Y coordinate represents the top of a rectangle, and therefore `height` goes down from there.  Since you want the rectangle to grow upwards from the bottom, you will need to update both the `y` and `height` attributes to get the correct result.

```js
document.querySelector('.ranger').addEventListener('input', function(event){
  const rectNeedle = document.getElementById('Rectangle-2');
  rectNeedle.setAttribute('y', 206 - event.target.value)
  rectNeedle.setAttribute('height', event.target.value)
})
```

```html
  <body>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" class="ranger">
    <p id="range-value"></p>
    <svg width="53px" height="207px" viewBox="0 0 53 207" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
        <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.3.3 (12081) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
        <title>moveLine</title>
        <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
        <defs></defs>
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
            <rect id="Rectangle-1" stroke="#979797" fill="#D8D8D8" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="1" y="1" width="51" height="205"></rect>
            <rect id="Rectangle-2" stroke="#979797" fill="#05243F" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="1" y="163" width="51" height="43"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
```

Comment: To me the main problem is i could not use line in that svg.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you could not.

Comment: I used line but it did not show any color filled in the line.

Comment: Does the example above work for you? That should provide a good starting point.  Have you also edited your SVG to remove the existing partial mercury level?  You'll need to do that. Then add the line in the correct place.

Comment: You can see this image http://imgur.com/19hPn4n. You will see the dark red needle but when i export that svg and copy paste the code or open from the browser i dont see that dark red line.

Comment: I can share the code if you want. I tried using <line> tag with the settings(x1,y1,x2,y2,stroke,strokeWidth, border) you see on the image directly on the code but did not work either.

Comment: As I said last time. Reduce your SVG to the bare minimum (eg. dark red line and a few numbers, like my example).  Then create a snippet or fiddle with your best effort at making it work. Then maybe we can look at what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's okay. We prefer [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) here though.

Comment: I have made a svg of rectangle. I want to move rectangle with animation https://jsfiddle.net/8nLp81n0/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One last question. Do i need to use two animate element like <animate attributeName="height" from="" to="" /> and <animate attributeName="y" from="" to="" /> inside rect dom?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  You can actually arrange things so that you could do it with only `height`, but for simplicity I would recommend you stick with the y + height approach.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8nLp81n0/7/ my animation is happening just opposite. It should start from bottom to top. Can you see, please?

Comment: ?? I don't understand your question. Your fiddle seems to be just my example with an animation element pasted in the CSS box.

Comment: Sorry i was fiddling with the code. That animation element is inside rect element. The animation is happening just the opposite of yours.

Comment: The animation is starting from the top to bottom which should be just the opposite. https://jsfiddle.net/8nLp81n0/19/

Comment: I tried to learn from the documentation but i dont see how y and height are related so that i can provide the right value to y and height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141962/discussion-between-milan-and-paul-lebeau).